# General question about ETL solutions for Azure for a small operation

Tags: azure-sql-database, etl

The way we use data is either retrieving survey data from other organizations, or creating survey instruments ourselves and soliciting organizations under our organization for data.

We have a database where our largest table is perhaps 10 million records. We extract and upload most of our data on an annual basis, with occasionally needing to ETL over large numbers of tables from organizations such as the Census, American Community Survey, etc. Our database is all on Azure and currently the way that I get databases from Census flat files/.csv files is by re-saving them as Excel and using the Excel import wizard.

All of the 'T' in ETL is happening within programmed procedures within my staging database before moving those tables (using Visual Studio) to our reporting database.

Is there a more sophisticated technology I should be using, and if so, what is it? All of my education in this matter comes from perusing Google and watching YouTube, so my grasp on all of the different terminology is lacking and searching on the internet for ETL is making it difficult to get to what I believe should be a simple answer.

For a while I thought we wanted to eventually graduate to using SSIS, but I learned that SSIS was something that was used primarily if you had a database on prem. I've tried looking at dynamic SQL using BULK INSERT to find that BULK INSERT doesn't work with Azure DBs. Etc.

Recently I've been learning about Azure Data Factory and something called Bulk Copy Program using Windows Power Shell.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to what technology I should look at for a small-scale BI reporting solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you using the [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction), it has good performance for the large data transfer.

[image]

Refence here: [Copy performance and scalability achievable using ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#copy-performance-and-scalability-achievable-using-adf)

[Copy Active](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) supports you using table data, query or stored procedure  to filter data in Source:

[image]

Sink support you select the destination table, stored procedure or auto create table(bulk insert) to receive the data:

[image]

Data Factory [Mapping Data Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview) provides more features for the data convert.

Ref: [Copy and transform data in Azure SQL Database by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database).

Hope this helps.